# How to collapse other navigation items

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

Okay ive searched everywhere for my problem and have seen nothing similar, maybe my research skills suck, which is very probable. Nevertheless, here is my problem.

I have a navigation made of ul and li and another ul and li inside of the outer li.

Using jquery, I can click the outer li to toggle the inner ul. This allows me to expand each navigation item individually. But I want the previous item to collapse when I click the next. All I could come up with was this:

```
<script>

$(function(){

    $(".main-nav").on("click",function(){
        $(".main-nav").find(".inner-nav").hide();
        $(this).find(".inner-nav").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

However whilst this does collapse every item, it doesnt allow to collapse the current item.
A portion of html is here:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="main-nav">
            <div class="nav-icon" id="dashboard-icon"></div>
            <a href="#">Dashboard</a>   
            <ul class="inner-nav">
                <li><div class="inner-nav-icon" id="stats-icon"></div><a href="#">Statistics</a></li>
                <li><div class="inner-nav-icon" id="log-icon"></div><a href="#">Log</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="main-nav">
            <div class="nav-icon" id="ticket-icon"></div>
            <a href="#">Support Tickets</a>
            <ul class="inner-nav">
                <li><div class="inner-nav-icon" id="browse-icon"></div><a href="#">Browse Active</a></li>
                <li><div class="inner-nav-icon" id="browse-icon"></div><a href="#">Browse Pending</a></li>
                <li><div class="inner-nav-icon" id="add-icon"></div><a href="#">Create A Ticket</a></li>
                <li><div class="inner-nav-icon" id="settings-nav-icon"></div><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>       
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while you use `toggle()` you can simply use `.not()`

```
$(function(){
    $(".main-nav").on("click",function(){
        $(".inner-nav").not($(this).find(".inner-nav")).hide();
        $(this).find(".inner-nav").toggle();
    });
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/pofjwhep/)